# Efeito fade na troca de imagens com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

O seguinte código faz um "fader de imagens" em uma `div` que tenho no meu documento. Porém, o efeito é muito 'seco', gostaria de ter uma transição durante a troca das imagens, tipo o efeito "fade" do jQuery.

```
var images = ['image-1.jpg','image-2.jpg','image-3.jpg','image-4.jpg','image-5.jpg','image-6.jpg'],
   index = 0,
   maxImages = images.length - 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
   var curImage = images[index];
   index = (index == maxImages) ? 0 : ++index;
   $('.header').css({'background-image':'url(./img/'+curImage+')'});
}, 1500);
```

Como eu poderia fazer?

Segue um fiddle com um [pequeno exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/WHhua/).

Comment: Que tipo de transição você espera conseguir? Uma imagem apagando e depois a outra aparecendo, uma imagem se "transformando" na outra... Creio que é possível fazer isso, mas não com `background-image` - segundo [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2983972/520779), não há propriedades customizáveis no `background-image`, então você vai ter que "simular" um background usando um outro elemento (e nesse sim, aplicar efeitos de transição).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha:

```
$('.header').css({'background-image':'url(./img/'+curImage+')'});
```

Você pode colocar um efeito de fadeout e fade in:

```
$('.header').fadeout().css({'background-image':'url(./img/'+curImage+')'}).fadein();
```

Comment: Não funciona amigo.. Faça o teste no Fiddle que adicionei..

Comment: Pra funcionar usando o fadeOut e o fadeIn seria algo parecido com isso: http://jsfiddle.net/WHhua/2/

Answer (score 5):

Use propriedade CSS `transition: background 500ms ease` diretamente na classe `.header` ou com o javascript:

```
$('.header').css({
    'background-image': 'url('+curImage+')',
    'transition': 'background 500ms ease'
});
```

Comment: Custei pra ver o efeito, achei até que não tinha funcionado, mas deu certo: http://jsfiddle.net/WHhua/1/

Answer (score 3):

Adicione `transition: background-image 300ms;` no seu ficheiro CSS.
É melhor adicionar no ficheiro CSS do que adicionar regras de CSS via javascript.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPWf8/)

CSS

```
.header{
    background: #333 url('http://flaticons.net/icons/Emotions/Cheeky.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 262px;
    transition: background-image 300ms; // linha nova!
                                        // 300ms é a velocidade (em milisegundos) da transição
}
```

---

Para browsers mais antigos que não suportam CSS transitions pode usar assim:

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/bu7Tu/)

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerImage"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 262px;
    background: #333
}
.headerImage {
    background: url('http://flaticons.net/icons/Emotions/Cheeky.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Javascript

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    var curImage = images[index];
    index = (index == maxImages) ? 0 : ++index;
    var $headerImage = $('.headerImage');
    $headerImage.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function () {
        $headerImage.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + curImage + ')'
        });
        $headerImage.animate({
            opacity: 1
        })
    });
}, 1500);
```