# Como exibir uma sequência de imagens a partir de um único link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Normalmente ao se utilizar plugins de galeria de imagens (Lightbox, Fancybox, etc), carregamos a imagem A a partir do thumb A, a imagem B a partir do thumb B e assim sucessivamente. Ao setarmos um relacionamento (`rel="x"`), conseguimos exibir diversas imagens da galeria utilizando "next" e "prev".

Até aí, ok... mas e quando eu tenho um set de imagens, mas não preciso exibir os thumbs do mesmo? Isso é, quero carregar esse set a partir de um único link específico?

Dando uma olhada na documentação dos plugins, não encontrei algo parecido. Consigo manipular o plugin dessa forma sem envolver desenvolvimento extra?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10580/129 Entretanto coloque o seu HTML na pergunta para podermos ajudar mais.

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado pelo rápido retorno, mas não é exatamente esse o problema. Nesse momento estou no trabalho e não vou conseguir criar um "fiddle", mas farei isso a noite seguindo a sua sugestão.

Porém, para adiantar (se ajudar), veja o exemplo de uso apresentado no Lightbox2 (http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2) para um set de quatro imagens. Perceba que são exibidos 4 thumbs e ao clicar em um deles abre-se um lightbox com uma galeria com next e prev. O que eu preciso ter é apenas um link, carregando essa mesma galeria (sem que seja necessário exibir os thumbs).

Comment: Uma idéia que me ocorre, sem *thumbnails*, seria nos *callbacks* executados antes e depois das imagens abrirem, comumente presentes nesses plugins, você enviar via AJAX o *offset* da imagem atualmente exibida, se alguma e, no **success**, construir dinamicamente o DOM necessário para o plugin trabalhar. Essa aplicação, devolveria dois *offsets*, anterior e posterior, se houverem, como numa paginação.

Comment: Escolha um plugin feito para galeria de imagens, que permita passar uma lista de URLs na inicialização.

Comment: Gambiarra não testada, e se fizar só o primeiro `<a>` com texto e o resto sem (invisivel)? `<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1">Ver Galeria</a><a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"></a><a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"></a><a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"></a>`

Comment: @BrunoAugusto daí você quebrou as minhas pernas... não sou DEV e entendi pouco o que disse... rs Mas vou guardar o comentário, pois pode ser útil em breve...

Comment: @bfavaretto vou tentar achar um com essa característica.

Comment: @brasofilo hahaha... Sensacional! Não tinha pensado nisso e pode ser que funcione. Vou testar hoje a noite. Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testei e é isso mesmo, é só fazer um conjunto de imagens, mas colocar conteúdo só no link da primeira. Usando o [exemplo](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) do [Lightbox](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2):

```
<div class="image-set">
    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward.">
        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."></a>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."></a>
</div>
```

Simplificado:

```
<div class="image-set">
    <a href="img1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set">GALERIA</a>
    <a href="img2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set"></a>
    <a href="img3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set"></a>
    <a href="img4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set"></a>
</div>
```

[Conferindo o código](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js#L120) do Lightbox, parece que é isso mesmo, não há função *"criar galeria a partir de um único link"*. Ele busca todos os `href`s e adiciona ao album de cada `data-lightbox`. A não ser que outro plugin ofereça essa funcionalidade específica, este é o *workaround*.