# Usar efeitos de Fade Out/In ao mudar CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Criei uma função que muda a imagem de fundo do `<body>` a cada 5 segundos, porém eu queria inserir também nessa função um efeito de transição entre as imagens: Fade Out para preto no inicio da transição e logo depois Fade In para a próxima imagem. Há algum jeito de fazer isso (seja com JQuery ou não)? Aqui está o código da função:

```
function BackgroundChange() {
    var image = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight"];
    var index = 0;
    window.setInterval(function BackgroundChangeSetImage() {
        index = index + 1;

        if ((index >= 0) && (index <= 7)) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style","background-image: url('images/image_" + image[index] + ".jpg');");
        } else {
            index = -1;
            return BackgroundChangeSetImage();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Ou até duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10560/129

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de dar fade in pelo javascript,faça de modo indireto,usando a função `toggleClass` do JQuery junto com transition do css3,exemplo:

CSS:

```
#imagem{
    webkit-transition:1s all;
    opacity:0;
}
.visivel{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#imagem").toggleClass("visivel")
$("#imagem").src = "source.png"
$("#imagem").toggleClass("visivel")
```

OBS:Toggle class checa se possui a classe `visivel` e remove caso possuir. Caso não tiver, adiciona.